# Does has_one associations need a foreign key reference

Tags: activerecord, foreign-keys

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base {
  has_one :bar
}
```

Does bar table in schema need a foreign key reference to foo_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Yes.  bar would have a FK to Foo

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base {
  belongs_to :foo 
 }
```

schema would be:

```
CREATE TABLE bars (
  id int,
  foo_id int,
  .....

}
```

has_one and has_many both define FK relationships,  has_one returns a singular object, has_many returns a collection.